# Are monotone continuous functions , injective?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Are all **monotone and continuous** functions one to one?

I know that not all injective functions are monotone,

However,if a function $f(x)$ is monotone and continuous,

Doesnt that mean that $\forall x,x'$ inside the domain of $f$: $$(x ≠ x') \implies(f(x) ≠ f(x'))$$

Because let's say that (WLOG) $f$ is strictly increasing in its domain,

then:
$$x<x' \implies f(x) < f(x')$$
$$x>x' \implies f(x) > f(x')$$

Comment: All strictly monotone functions are injective, regardless of whether or not they are continuous.  It is an immediate consequence of the definitions.  Do note that "monotone" without the word "strictly" to some authors will have in their definitions $\leq$ rather than $<$.

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you for your responses. thats what I thought !